# Accessing global variable in function

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Ok, so here is my code that is working perfectly and just as it supposed to.

```
function setCanvasBackground (src){ 

    var source = document.getElementById('hiddenCanvas');
    var source_ctx = source.getContext('2d');
    var destination = document.getElementById('visibleCanvas');
    var destin_ctx = destination.getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        source.width = img.width;
        source.height = img.height;
        source_ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        destin_ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0, img.width/4, img.height/4);
    }
    img.src = src;
};
```

However, if I move variables outside the function, so they can be accessed from other functions, the code just is not working. Here is what I do:

```
var source = document.getElementById('hiddenCanvas');
var source_ctx = source.getContext('2d');
var destination = document.getElementById('visibleCanvas');
var destin_ctx = destination.getContext('2d');

function setCanvasBackground (src){ 
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        source.width = img.width;
        source.height = img.height;
        source_ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height); 
        destin_ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0, img.width/4, img.height/4);
    }
img.src = src;
};
```

All JavaScript code is in separate file and not in HTML. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably trying to select elements that haven't been loaded into the DOM yet. First place you should look would be your browser's developer console.

Comment: You can fix that by _assigning_ values to the global variables inside setCanvasBackground, or do it in window.onload or document/ready handler.

Comment: Can you reproduce a running example on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var source, source_ctx, destination, destin_ctx;

window.onload=function() {
    source = document.getElementById('hiddenCanvas');
    source_ctx = source.getContext('2d');
    destination = document.getElementById('visibleCanvas');
    destin_ctx = destination.getContext('2d');
}

function setCanvasBackground (src){ 
    // ...
};
```

You cannot access elements before they are loaded. This will result in an attempt to access elements that doesn't exist.

Comment: I did just the same, with just one change - I declared variables right in window.onload function, but it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add a **callback** into setCanvasBackground:

```
function setCanvasBackground(src, callback) {
    [...snip...]
    img.onload = function(){
        source.width = img.width;
        source.height = img.height;
        source_ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        destin_ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0, img.width/4, img.height/4);

        // all set now:
        callback(source, source_ctx, destination, destin_ctx);
    }
    [...snip...]
}
```

...and then, when you call setCanvasBackground, add a function that won't be called until the image has finished loading:

```
setCanvasBackground(..., function(src, src_ctx, dest, dest_ctx) {
    alert("source.width:  " + src.width);
});
```